# How to get website to accept client program data and display them

Tags: javascript, ios, web-services, post

I need to create a website that accepts data from client programs (swift programs /IOS apps) in the form of images and strings, and display/store these data on the website.

What is the correct way for a client program to send some data to a website and the website to receive them then display the data?

Edit: I saw some answers that Django python framework can be good for making dynamic website.  Would Django be good for my scenarios here?  Note that I am very newbie at web development.

Comment: Probably a restful API would be the best choice

Comment: Is that easy to do from the website perspective since I have to implement this site as well as the swift client programs.  I used rest before but only as client.

Comment: Sure... On the webserver you define a endpoint to receive a POST (where you also validate user permissions) then on the clients you just send requests to that endpoint (which is basically a url) as you have done before. It's really the way to go...

Comment: Right now I am running a client program that is modifying the files inside my website directory but this doesnt seem like a good idea if there is a lot of clients although it is kinda working.